# in odoo14 , i'm sending a notficition to the manager , is there any option to add a button in the notification?

Tags: python, odoo

i want to add a button in the notification so the manager can answer with yes or no
def Send_notificiton():
for note in self:
note.manager_id.user_id.notify_danger(message="asking for permission")

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 14 you can't set actions in a notification.

But You can write a module with JS and create custom notification what have actions option or others.

So you can develop new module for it, but the original odoo 14 notification can't do it.

Comment: `notification.include({
        icon_mapping: {
            success: "fa-thumbs-up",
            danger: "fa-exclamation-triangle",
            warning: "fa-exclamation",
            info: "fa-info",
            default: "fa-lightbulb-o",
        },`

Comment: i'm new in js , could you help me in adding a button in this code ?

Comment: @AbdullahMeaad Sorry, I don't revisit this site long ago. I hope you can implement the button what You want.